# Resetting state when rendering a component at different positions

Tags: reactjs

I've been reading the **Preserving and Resetting State** article on the **Learn** section at [react.dev](https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#) and I'm confused with the 1st challenge. The article says that to preserve state, the component needs to be rendered at the same position. The challenge code is as follows:

```
export default function App() {
  const [showHint, setShowHint] = useState(false);
  if (showHint) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p><i>Hint: Your favorite city?</i></p>
        <Form />
        <button onClick={() => {
          setShowHint(false);
        }}>Hide hint</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Form />
      <button onClick={() => {
        setShowHint(true);
      }}>Show hint</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When `showHint` is `true` the `<Form />` is the second child of the `<div>`. When `showHint` is `false`, the `<Form />` is the first child. That I completely understand.

What I wrote as a solution, which is the provided solution for this exercise is:

```
export default function App() {
  const [showHint, setShowHint] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      {showHint && (
        <p>
          <i>Hint: Your favorite city?</i>
        </p>
      )}
      <Form />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setShowHint(!showHint);
        }}
      >
        {showHint ? "Hide hint" : "Show Hint"}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here we have one return statement. The `<p>` gets rendered only if `showHint` is `true`. Although we use a different conditional structure(the &&) to render the `<p>` I can't understand why this is any different as the first code example above. If `showHint` is true, the `<Form />` will become the second child of the `<div>`. So the position changes, isn't it? My question is why is this any different from the first code example with the two different conditional branches. Does the && conditional structure somehow works differently? Does it input something(like a null element/empty element of sorts) when `showHint` is false in order to preserve the tree structure and so the position of `<Form />` gets preserved?

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside for a moment that the solution version is "better" simply for DRY purposes...

Keep in mind that everything React does in terms of maintaining the component hierarchy, optimizing rendering, etc. is all based not on the *code* that we're seeing, but on the *returned result* from that code.

In the solution, the same overall JSX structure is always returned.  I don't know if as you suggest there's some inner `null` value that React sees, but it seems to me that when the condition within the returned JSX is observed/evaluated, React sees what's happening.  That is, *the entire structure* (conditions and all) is returned to React and evaluated by React.

In the problem however, React *doesn't* observe that condition.  In that case the programmer has taken that responsibility away from the framework and internalized it in their own code.  So the condition is evaluated before the result is returned and React never sees it.  As far as React is concerned, an entirely different (albeit similar, but not enough) JSX tree was returned from the component.

Even outside of logical errors that can occur as a result of the child component(s) not being able to maintain state, in larger and more complex structures this could also drastically reduce any performance gains from React's rendering optimizations.  (For back-end developers, consider it analagous to dynamically building SQL queries vs. re-using a query with different parameter values.  The latter allows the DB to optimize the execution plan, the former does not.)

---

Here's an example of the problem, in which `<Form/>` maintains an internal state value.  Observe that you can click the button in the `<Form/>` and increase `counter` all you like, but as soon as you click the button in `<App/>` to cause its own re-render, that `counter` state is lost:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Form = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCounter(counter + 1);
        }}
      >
        {counter}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const [showHint, setShowHint] = useState(false);
  if (showHint) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <i>Hint: Your favorite city?</i>
        </p>
        <Form />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setShowHint(false);
          }}
        >
          Hide hint
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Form />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setShowHint(true);
        }}
      >
        Show hint
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @David. I believed that changes in the parent component, for example rendering the `<p>` above the `<Form />` when `showHint` is true will affect the tree structure that gets rendered. So one would be:
```
<div>
<Form />
</div>
and the other 
<div>
<p>
<Form />
</div>
```
and that would be enough of a tree structure change to discard the state.

Comment: @TasosPoursaitidis: The `<p>` doesn't really have anything to do with the problem, unless I'm misunderstanding the example.  With or without the `<p>`, the problem I'm seeing is that two different `<Form>` instances are conditionally rendering, which would cause their internal state to be lost.  The `<p>` (and the "order of rendering" description I suppose) appear to just be the otherwise contrived example used to demonstrate what might lead to that problem.  I've updated the answer to also include a live example of the problem.

Comment: @TasosPoursaitidis: I suppose the `<p>` *is* somewhat related, in that without it React may see enough similarity between the component trees to optimize the rendering.  This similarity isn't something React observes *in the code*, but rather *in the returned value* from the component's rendering.  So the `<p>` changes that value.  The more I tinker with it, the more I see the pattern.  Even with that kind of optimization though, I'd still always recommend explicitly maintaining the tree of elements as shown in the solution.  Even just for DRY purposes.

Comment: The more I tinker with this, the more I learn about it.  Updating the answer now...

Comment: I would like to see what exactly React sees as a tree structure. Maybe then I'll gain a deeper understanding that will stop my confusion. One way I imagine it is like the DOM the browser see. But I may be incorrect thinking it that way.